# How to efficiently get all instances from deeper level in Cocoa model?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In my Cocoa Mac app I have an instance `A` which contains an unordered set of instances `B` which in turn has an ordered set of instances `C`. An instance of `C` can only be in one instance `B` and `B` only in one `A`.

I would like to have an unordered set of all instances `C` available on instance `A`. I could enumerate over all instances `B` each time, but that seems expensive for something I need to do often. However, I am a bit worried that keeping track of instances `C` in `A` could become cumbersome and be the cause of  inconsistencies, for example if an instance `C` gets removed from `B` but not from `A`.

*Solution 1* –
Use a `NSMutableSet` in `A` and add or remove `C` instances whenever I do the same operation in `B`.

*Solution 2* –
Use a weak referenced `NSHashTable` in `A`. When deleting a `C` from `B` it should disappear for `A` as well.

*Solution 3* –
Use key value observing in `A` to keep track of changes in `B`, and update a `NSMutableSet` in `A` accordingly.

*Solution 4* –
Simply iterate over all instances `B` to create the set whenever I need it.

Which way is best? Are there any other approaches that I missed?

NB I don't and won't use CoreData for this app.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Do you know that this is where you spend a lot of time? You should probably do profiling before attempting to optimize.

Comment: am I take it right all, instances of C are unique among all data?

Comment: No, this code I have not profiled yet, mostly because I am still designing it and there is much to profile just yet. It seemed a common enough problem though to ask how others have implemented this.

Yes, all instances of `C` are unique. Sorry if that wasn't clear. It should follow logically from `C` being only in one `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` has a set of `B` objects, and each `B` object has a set of `C` objects, you can do:

```
NSSet * allCObjectsInA = [anAObject valueForKeyPath:@"bObjects.@distinctUnionOfSets.cObjects"];
```

This is assuming that you can access `A`'s `B` objects via a method called `- (NSSet *) bObjects;`, and `B`'s `C` objects with `-(NSSet *) cObjects;`

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. Those set and array operators are indeed a good option I had overlooked. As `B` contains an array of `C` I'd probably go with another operator than `@distinctUnionOfSets`, probably `@unionOfArrays`.

Comment: Correction, I had to use `@distinctUnionOfArrays`, as the `@unionOf...` operators can only be used on an array, not a set. Anyway, thanks again for this neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really needs to optimize your code, you shouldn't bother with caching: enumerate over all instances of B each time you need your set.